# How to know if the band calculation result is correct?

Tags: quantum-espresso, band-structure, bandgap

I did a band calculation (I'll leave the input and output files below), but I don't know how to identify whether my result is right or wrong, can anyone help me?

Arquivo.in

```
&bands
  outdir='./tmp'
  prefix='pwscf'
  filband='bands.dat'
/
```

Arquivo.out

```
    0.0000  -32.6938
    0.1964  -32.6938
    0.4714  -32.6933
    0.6679  -32.6933
    0.9429  -32.6923
    1.1393  -32.6923
    2.1214  -32.6918
    2.3178  -32.6918
    3.2214  -32.6925
    3.4178  -32.6925
    3.6928  -32.6918
    3.8892  -32.6918
    4.1642  -32.6915
    4.3607  -32.6915
    4.3607  -32.6918
    4.5571  -32.6918

    0.0000  -19.8333
    0.1964  -19.8334
    0.4714  -19.8193
    0.6679  -19.8194
    0.9429  -19.7912
    1.1393  -19.7912
    2.1214  -19.7770
    2.3178  -19.7770
    3.2214  -19.7982
    3.4178  -19.7983
    3.6928  -19.7771
    3.8892  -19.7771
    4.1642  -19.7700
    4.3607  -19.7700
    4.3607  -19.7771
    4.5571  -19.7771

    0.0000  -17.2903
    0.1964  -17.2601
    0.4714  -17.1882
    0.6679  -17.1577
    0.9429  -16.9193
    1.1393  -16.8905
    2.1214  -16.6769
    2.3178  -16.6733
    3.2214  -17.0008
    3.4178  -16.9705
    3.6928  -16.7184
    3.8892  -16.6982
    4.1642  -16.6025
    4.3607  -16.6025
    4.3607  -16.7184
    4.5571  -16.6982

    0.0000  -16.8132
    0.1964  -16.8886
    0.4714  -16.7568
    0.6679  -16.8286
    0.9429  -16.6357
    1.1393  -16.6887
    2.1214  -16.6147
    2.3178  -16.6180
    3.2214  -16.6647
    3.4178  -16.7262
    3.6928  -16.5743
    3.8892  -16.6021
    4.1642  -16.5125
    4.3607  -16.5126
    4.3607  -16.5742
    4.5571  -16.6021

    0.0000  -15.9973
    0.1964  -15.8812
    0.4714  -15.9653
    0.6679  -15.8590
    0.9429  -15.8916
    1.1393  -15.8270
    2.1214  -15.8969
    2.3178  -15.8957
    3.2214  -15.9081
    3.4178  -15.8263
    3.6928  -15.8892
    3.8892  -15.8742
    4.1642  -15.9679
    4.3607  -15.9679
    4.3607  -15.8893
    4.5571  -15.8744

    0.0000  -14.8058
    0.1964  -14.9498
    0.4714  -15.0087
    0.6679  -15.0914
    0.9429  -15.3765
    1.1393  -15.4140
    2.1214  -15.4895
    2.3178  -15.5099
    3.2214  -15.2832
    3.4178  -15.3283
    3.6928  -15.4846
    3.8892  -15.4921
    4.1642  -15.3497
    4.3607  -15.3500
    4.3607  -15.4849
    4.5571  -15.4919

    0.0000  -14.8057
    0.1964  -14.8058
    0.4714  -14.8302
    0.6679  -14.8323
    0.9429  -14.8824
    1.1393  -14.8936
    2.1214  -15.1296
    2.3178  -15.0948
    3.2214  -14.8771
    3.4178  -14.8782
    3.6928  -15.0664
    3.8892  -15.0579
    4.1642  -15.2979
    4.3607  -15.2974
    4.3607  -15.0649
    4.5571  -15.0595

    0.0000  -14.7479
    0.1964  -14.8057
    0.4714  -14.7275
    0.6679  -14.8100
    0.9429  -14.8583
    1.1393  -14.8712
    2.1214  -14.8994
    2.3178  -14.9002
    3.2214  -14.7424
    3.4178  -14.8158
    3.6928  -14.9200
    3.8892  -14.9227
    4.1642  -14.9662
    4.3607  -14.9586
    4.3607  -14.9220
    4.5571  -14.9198

    0.0000  -14.3209
    0.1964  -14.1611
    0.4714  -14.4238
    0.6679  -14.2991
    0.9429  -14.5727
    1.1393  -14.5439
    2.1214  -14.5660
    2.3178  -14.5472
    3.2214  -14.5891
    3.4178  -14.5170
    3.6928  -14.6305
    3.8892  -14.6340
    4.1642  -14.7152
    4.3607  -14.7272
    4.3607  -14.6260
    4.5571  -14.6360

    0.0000  -14.0087
    0.1964  -14.0089
    0.4714  -14.1815
    0.6679  -14.2056
    0.9429  -14.3849
    1.1393  -14.3998
    2.1214  -14.4178
    2.3178  -14.4594
    3.2214  -14.3812
    3.4178  -14.3924
    3.6928  -14.4900
    3.8892  -14.4978
    4.1642  -14.4856
    4.3607  -14.4850
    4.3607  -14.4931
    4.5571  -14.4959

    0.0000  -14.0086
    0.1964  -14.0088
    0.4714  -14.0537
    0.6679  -14.0545
    0.9429  -14.1347
    1.1393  -14.1352
    2.1214  -14.1709
    2.3178  -14.1712
    3.2214  -14.0920
    3.4178  -14.0907
    3.6928  -14.0621
    3.8892  -14.0703
    4.1642  -14.1323
    4.3607  -14.1340
    4.3607  -14.0657
    4.5571  -14.0742

    0.0000  -13.8711
    0.1964  -13.8708
    0.4714  -13.8976
    0.6679  -13.8971
    0.9429  -13.9494
    1.1393  -13.9487
    2.1214  -13.9748
    2.3178  -13.9740
    3.2214  -13.9632
    3.4178  -13.9626
    3.6928  -14.0420
    3.8892  -14.0312
    4.1642  -13.9731
    4.3607  -13.9661
    4.3607  -14.0429
    4.5571  -14.0329

    0.0000  -13.8711
    0.1964  -13.8708
    0.4714  -13.7025
    0.6679  -13.6776
    0.9429  -13.6475
    1.1393  -13.6437
    2.1214  -13.7485
    2.3178  -13.7476
    3.2214  -13.5720
    3.4178  -13.5637
    3.6928  -13.6890
    3.8892  -13.6893
    4.1642  -13.6908
    4.3607  -13.6916
    4.3607  -13.6823
    4.5571  -13.6813

    0.0000  -13.3179
    0.1964  -13.3180
    0.4714  -13.4149
    0.6679  -13.4186
    0.9429  -13.3721
    1.1393  -13.3639
    2.1214  -13.2625
    2.3178  -13.2635
    3.2214  -13.4176
    3.4178  -13.4021
    3.6928  -13.3409
    3.8892  -13.3360
    4.1642  -13.4167
    4.3607  -13.4149
    4.3607  -13.3431
    4.5571  -13.3408

    0.0000  -13.3178
    0.1964  -13.3179
    0.4714  -13.2993
    0.6679  -13.2993
    0.9429  -13.2716
    1.1393  -13.2710
    2.1214  -13.2190
    2.3178  -13.2201
    3.2214  -13.3122
    3.4178  -13.3193
    3.6928  -13.1811
    3.8892  -13.1823
    4.1642  -13.0459
    4.3607  -13.0456
    4.3607  -13.1820
    4.5571  -13.1812

    0.0000  -12.9920
    0.1964  -13.0222
    0.4714  -12.9428
    0.6679  -12.9614
    0.9429  -12.9126
    1.1393  -12.9137
    2.1214  -12.9341
    2.3178  -12.9190
    3.2214  -12.9072
    3.4178  -12.9154
    3.6928  -12.9174
    3.8892  -12.9148
    4.1642  -12.9474
    4.3607  -12.9508
    4.3607  -12.9172
    4.5571  -12.9148

    0.0000  -11.8440
    0.1964  -11.8440
    0.4714  -11.9127
    0.6679  -11.9143
    0.9429  -12.0584
    1.1393  -12.0632
    2.1214  -12.1374
    2.3178  -12.1445
    3.2214  -11.9983
    3.4178  -12.0019
    3.6928  -12.0777
    3.8892  -12.0816
    4.1642  -12.0205
    4.3607  -12.0211
    4.3607  -12.0770
    4.5571  -12.0811

    0.0000  -11.8440
    0.1964  -11.8440
    0.4714  -11.8156
    0.6679  -11.8156
    0.9429  -11.7614
    1.1393  -11.7614
    2.1214  -11.7354
    2.3178  -11.7355
    3.2214  -11.7970
    3.4178  -11.7965
    3.6928  -11.7953
    3.8892  -11.7947
    4.1642  -11.8813
    4.3607  -11.8805
    4.3607  -11.7960
    4.5571  -11.7952

    0.0000   -9.2875
    0.1964   -9.2856
    0.4714   -9.1772
    0.6679   -9.1758
    0.9429   -8.9686
    1.1393   -8.9680
    2.1214   -8.8695
    2.3178   -8.8693
    3.2214   -9.0186
    3.4178   -9.0178
    3.6928   -8.8665
    3.8892   -8.8662
    4.1642   -8.8143
    4.3607   -8.8142
    4.3607   -8.8663
    4.5571   -8.8661

    0.0000   -6.1499
    0.1964   -6.1534
    0.4714   -5.9582
    0.6679   -5.9610
    0.9429   -5.5389
    1.1393   -5.5412
    2.1214   -5.3030
    2.3178   -5.3064
    3.2214   -5.6412
    3.4178   -5.6432
    3.6928   -5.2609
    3.8892   -5.2627
    4.1642   -5.0566
    4.3607   -5.0569
    4.3607   -5.2577
    4.5571   -5.2595

    0.0000   -5.3121
    0.1964   -5.3060
    0.4714   -5.2077
    0.6679   -5.2025
    0.9429   -4.9916
    1.1393   -4.9867
    2.1214   -4.8819
    2.3178   -4.8749
    3.2214   -5.0328
    3.4178   -5.0288
    3.6928   -4.8160
    3.8892   -4.8126
    4.1642   -4.6581
    4.3607   -4.6579
    4.3607   -4.8185
    4.5571   -4.8149

    0.0000   -3.9888
    0.1964   -3.9926
    0.4714   -3.9107
    0.6679   -3.9104
    0.9429   -3.9379
    1.1393   -3.9346
    2.1214   -3.9375
    2.3178   -3.9361
    3.2214   -3.9163
    3.4178   -3.9121
    3.6928   -3.9544
    3.8892   -3.9496
    4.1642   -4.0329
    4.3607   -4.0323
    4.3607   -3.9572
    4.5571   -3.9552

    0.0000   -3.8425
    0.1964   -3.8427
    0.4714   -3.8282
    0.6679   -3.8318
    0.9429   -3.6344
    1.1393   -3.6510
    2.1214   -3.6063
    2.3178   -3.6234
    3.2214   -3.7584
    3.4178   -3.7640
    3.6928   -3.6847
    3.8892   -3.6954
    4.1642   -3.7202
    4.3607   -3.7255
    4.3607   -3.7032
    4.5571   -3.7106

    0.0000   -3.8425
    0.1964   -3.8426
    0.4714   -3.7556
    0.6679   -3.7550
    0.9429   -3.5847
    1.1393   -3.5742
    2.1214   -3.4988
    2.3178   -3.4862
    3.2214   -3.5414
    3.4178   -3.5415
    3.6928   -3.3875
    3.8892   -3.3830
    4.1642   -3.2747
    4.3607   -3.2641
    4.3607   -3.3870
    4.5571   -3.3806

    0.0000   -2.9666
    0.1964   -2.9668
    0.4714   -3.0114
    0.6679   -3.0136
    0.9429   -2.9243
    1.1393   -2.9256
    2.1214   -2.5730
    2.3178   -2.5789
    3.2214   -3.0693
    3.4178   -3.0720
    3.6928   -2.9686
    3.8892   -2.9671
    4.1642   -3.0240
    4.3607   -3.0250
    4.3607   -2.9044
    4.5571   -2.9076

    0.0000   -2.9666
    0.1964   -2.9667
    0.4714   -2.8255
    0.6679   -2.8274
    0.9429   -2.5059
    1.1393   -2.5121
    2.1214   -2.3796
    2.3178   -2.3648
    3.2214   -2.5709
    3.4178   -2.5753
    3.6928   -2.3679
    3.8892   -2.3700
    4.1642   -2.4977
    4.3607   -2.4975
    4.3607   -2.4319
    4.5571   -2.4306

    0.0000   -1.6552
    0.1964   -1.6529
    0.4714   -1.7683
    0.6679   -1.7603
    0.9429   -2.0416
    1.1393   -2.0310
    2.1214   -2.2770
    2.3178   -2.2872
    3.2214   -1.9290
    3.4178   -1.9182
    3.6928   -2.0290
    3.8892   -2.0291
    4.1642   -1.8316
    4.3607   -1.8419
    4.3607   -2.0171
    4.5571   -2.0185

    0.0000   -1.6552
    0.1964   -1.6529
    0.4714   -1.6002
    0.6679   -1.5952
    0.9429   -1.5115
    1.1393   -1.5087
    2.1214   -1.4567
    2.3178   -1.4606
    3.2214   -1.5395
    3.4178   -1.5356
    3.6928   -1.5258
    3.8892   -1.5255
    4.1642   -1.5057
    4.3607   -1.5057
    4.3607   -1.4970
    4.5571   -1.4974

    0.0000   -1.4524
    0.1964   -1.4514
    0.4714   -1.2338
    0.6679   -1.2377
    0.9429   -1.0351
    1.1393   -1.0430
    2.1214   -1.3480
    2.3178   -1.3522
    3.2214   -0.9476
    3.4178   -0.9581
    3.6928   -1.2556
    3.8892   -1.2609
    4.1642   -1.4292
    4.3607   -1.4289
    4.3607   -1.2751
    4.5571   -1.2803

    0.0000   -0.9944
    0.1964   -0.9837
    0.4714   -0.8669
    0.6679   -0.8546
    0.9429   -0.8235
    1.1393   -0.8265
    2.1214   -0.6360
    2.3178   -0.6242
    3.2214   -0.9014
    3.4178   -0.9004
    3.6928   -0.6123
    3.8892   -0.6048
    4.1642   -0.7243
    4.3607   -0.7279
    4.3607   -0.6750
    4.5571   -0.6742

    0.0000   -0.5836
    0.1964   -0.5859
    0.4714   -0.6999
    0.6679   -0.7038
    0.9429   -0.5253
    1.1393   -0.5336
    2.1214   -0.4833
    2.3178   -0.4211
    3.2214   -0.5936
    3.4178   -0.6032
    3.6928   -0.5486
    3.8892   -0.5469
    4.1642   -0.2947
    4.3607   -0.2953
    4.3607   -0.4611
    4.5571   -0.4352

    0.0000   -0.5836
    0.1964   -0.5859
    0.4714   -0.5019
    0.6679   -0.5049
    0.9429   -0.3919
    1.1393   -0.3667
    2.1214   -0.3211
    2.3178   -0.3713
    3.2214   -0.4363
    3.4178   -0.4098
    3.6928   -0.2769
    3.8892   -0.2710
    4.1642   -0.2324
    4.3607   -0.2534
    4.3607   -0.2896
    4.5571   -0.3116

    0.0000   -0.4086
    0.1964   -0.4283
    0.4714   -0.3450
    0.6679   -0.3755
    0.9429   -0.2213
    1.1393   -0.2301
    2.1214   -0.1344
    2.3178   -0.1793
    3.2214   -0.2695
    3.4178   -0.3013
    3.6928   -0.1777
    3.8892   -0.2276
    4.1642   -0.2272
    4.3607   -0.2305
    4.3607   -0.1747
    4.5571   -0.2010

    0.0000    0.2541
    0.1964    0.2524
    0.4714    0.1854
    0.6679    0.2142
    0.9429   -0.0469
    1.1393   -0.0478
    2.1214   -0.0119
    2.3178    0.0139
    3.2214    0.0281
    3.4178    0.0529
    3.6928   -0.0608
    3.8892   -0.0119
    4.1642   -0.0488
    4.3607   -0.0080
    4.3607   -0.0672
    4.5571   -0.0311

    0.0000    0.2541
    0.1964    0.2524
    0.4714    0.2818
    0.6679    0.2904
    0.9429    0.3988
    1.1393    0.3974
    2.1214    0.3640
    2.3178    0.3729
    3.2214    0.3434
    3.4178    0.3458
    3.6928    0.3321
    3.8892    0.3313
    4.1642    0.2179
    4.3607    0.2259
    4.3607    0.3223
    4.5571    0.2918

    0.0000    0.3396
    0.1964    0.3410
    0.4714    0.3849
    0.6679    0.3558
    0.9429    0.4802
    1.1393    0.4562
    2.1214    0.4302
    2.3178    0.4284
    3.2214    0.4448
    3.4178    0.4076
    3.6928    0.4647
    3.8892    0.4748
    4.1642    0.5103
    4.3607    0.5140
    4.3607    0.4193
    4.5571    0.4288

    0.0000    0.9854
    0.1964    0.9826
    0.4714    0.8568
    0.6679    0.8648
    0.9429    0.6184
    1.1393    0.6462
    2.1214    0.5947
    2.3178    0.5930
    3.2214    0.6639
    3.4178    0.7049
    3.6928    0.5661
    3.8892    0.5474
    4.1642    0.5633
    4.3607    0.5469
    4.3607    0.5435
    4.5571    0.5765

    0.0000    0.9854
    0.1964    0.9826
    0.4714    0.9684
    0.6679    0.9684
    0.9429    0.8784
    1.1393    0.8865
    2.1214    0.8821
    2.3178    0.8841
    3.2214    0.8344
    3.4178    0.8257
    3.6928    0.8151
    3.8892    0.8149
    4.1642    0.7666
    4.3607    0.7895
    4.3607    0.8698
    4.5571    0.8286

    0.0000    1.1948
    0.1964    1.2004
    0.4714    1.0814
    0.6679    1.0637
    0.9429    1.0166
    1.1393    0.9727
    2.1214    0.9890
    2.3178    0.9937
    3.2214    1.0209
    3.4178    1.0006
    3.6928    0.9200
    3.8892    0.9267
    4.1642    0.8392
    4.3607    0.8342
    4.3607    0.9235
    4.5571    0.9472

    0.0000    1.1948
    0.1964    1.2004
    0.4714    1.1502
    0.6679    1.1719
    0.9429    1.1186
    1.1393    1.1503
    2.1214    1.1893
    2.3178    1.1684
    3.2214    1.2287
    3.4178    1.2447
    3.6928    1.1868
    3.8892    1.1712
    4.1642    1.0607
    4.3607    1.0463
    4.3607    1.2609
    4.5571    1.2592

    0.0000    1.4302
    0.1964    1.4367
    0.4714    1.5799
    0.6679    1.5800
    0.9429    1.4427
    1.1393    1.4415
    2.1214    1.4736
    2.3178    1.4581
    3.2214    1.5225
    3.4178    1.5155
    3.6928    1.4755
    3.8892    1.5066
    4.1642    1.4055
    4.3607    1.3902
    4.3607    1.4436
    4.5571    1.4225

    0.0000    2.0661
    0.1964    2.0686
    0.4714    1.8253
    0.6679    1.8330
    0.9429    1.6983
    1.1393    1.7256
    2.1214    1.5349
    2.3178    1.5644
    3.2214    1.6612
    3.4178    1.6784
    3.6928    1.5549
    3.8892    1.5431
    4.1642    1.6849
    4.3607    1.7032
    4.3607    1.5067
    4.5571    1.5362

    0.0000    2.0661
    0.1964    2.0686
    0.4714    2.0313
    0.6679    2.0302
    0.9429    1.8844
    1.1393    1.8633
    2.1214    1.6875
    2.3178    1.7195
    3.2214    1.9701
    3.4178    1.9658
    3.6928    1.7997
    3.8892    1.8115
    4.1642    1.8650
    4.3607    1.8694
    4.3607    1.8776
    4.5571    1.8807

    0.0000    2.1630
    0.1964    2.1701
    0.4714    2.2611
    0.6679    2.2612
    0.9429    2.0769
    1.1393    2.0722
    2.1214    2.0480
    2.3178    2.0059
    3.2214    2.1298
    3.4178    2.1267
    3.6928    2.1553
    3.8892    2.1219
    4.1642    2.2640
    4.3607    2.2418
    4.3607    2.1317
    4.5571    2.1172

    0.0000    2.4318
    0.1964    2.4253
    0.4714    2.3408
    0.6679    2.3452
    0.9429    2.3654
    1.1393    2.3543
    2.1214    2.2567
    2.3178    2.2552
    3.2214    2.3121
    3.4178    2.3093
    3.6928    2.3336
    3.8892    2.3379
    4.1642    2.3293
    4.3607    2.3184
    4.3607    2.2155
    4.5571    2.2098

    0.0000    2.4318
    0.1964    2.4254
    0.4714    2.4185
    0.6679    2.4152
    0.9429    2.4558
    1.1393    2.4731
    2.1214    2.4230
    2.3178    2.4207
    3.2214    2.4464
    3.4178    2.4485
    3.6928    2.4495
    3.8892    2.4394
    4.1642    2.4537
    4.3607    2.4775
    4.3607    2.4686
    4.5571    2.4649

    0.0000    2.7514
    0.1964    2.7720
    0.4714    2.6962
    0.6679    2.6834
    0.9429    2.5212
    1.1393    2.5148
    2.1214    2.6030
    2.3178    2.5916
    3.2214    2.6515
    3.4178    2.6464
    3.6928    2.4894
    3.8892    2.4905
    4.1642    2.5532
    4.3607    2.5407
    4.3607    2.5877
    4.5571    2.6039

    0.0000    2.8683
    0.1964    2.8716
    0.4714    2.8323
    0.6679    2.8438
    0.9429    2.7153
    1.1393    2.7354
    2.1214    2.6577
    2.3178    2.6704
    3.2214    2.7952
    3.4178    2.7827
    3.6928    2.7293
    3.8892    2.7376
    4.1642    2.5667
    4.3607    2.5580
    4.3607    2.6873
    4.5571    2.6725

    0.0000    2.8683
    0.1964    2.8716
    0.4714    2.8895
    0.6679    2.8940
    0.9429    2.8457
    1.1393    2.8243
    2.1214    2.7416
    2.3178    2.7653
    3.2214    2.8371
    3.4178    2.8596
    3.6928    2.8099
    3.8892    2.8221
    4.1642    3.1078
    4.3607    3.1131
    4.3607    2.8128
    4.5571    2.8238

    0.0000    3.1096
    0.1964    3.0990
    0.4714    3.0828
    0.6679    3.0802
    0.9429    3.1306
    1.1393    3.1111
    2.1214    2.9793
    2.3178    2.9711
    3.2214    3.0800
    3.4178    3.0668
    3.6928    3.1172
    3.8892    3.0976
    4.1642    3.1081
    4.3607    3.1177
    4.3607    3.1355
    4.5571    3.1123

    0.0000    3.4788
    0.1964    3.4599
    0.4714    3.3976
    0.6679    3.4084
    0.9429    3.2296
    1.1393    3.2505
    2.1214    3.2357
    2.3178    3.2217
    3.2214    3.3050
    3.4178    3.3130
    3.6928    3.2100
    3.8892    3.2194
    4.1642    3.1678
    4.3607    3.1596
    4.3607    3.1868
    4.5571    3.1986

    0.0000    3.4808
    0.1964    3.4928
    0.4714    3.4629
    0.6679    3.4597
    0.9429    3.3579
    1.1393    3.3776
    2.1214    3.3677
    2.3178    3.4007
    3.2214    3.3811
    3.4178    3.3829
    3.6928    3.3411
    3.8892    3.3724
    4.1642    3.2864
    4.3607    3.3100
    4.3607    3.3404
    4.5571    3.3650

    0.0000    3.4808
    0.1964    3.4928
    0.4714    3.5620
    0.6679    3.5548
    0.9429    3.5393
    1.1393    3.5242
    2.1214    3.5329
    2.3178    3.5262
    3.2214    3.5689
    3.4178    3.5536
    3.6928    3.4805
    3.8892    3.4665
    4.1642    3.3812
    4.3607    3.3731
    4.3607    3.4902
    4.5571    3.4924

    0.0000    3.7154
    0.1964    3.6993
    0.4714    3.5938
    0.6679    3.5953
    0.9429    3.6381
    1.1393    3.6318
    2.1214    3.6748
    2.3178    3.6672
    3.2214    3.5854
    3.4178    3.5910
    3.6928    3.5545
    3.8892    3.5630
    4.1642    3.4033
    4.3607    3.4247
    4.3607    3.5520
    4.5571    3.5525

    0.0000    3.7154
    0.1964    3.6994
    0.4714    3.6748
    0.6679    3.6603
    0.9429    3.7431
    1.1393    3.7559
    2.1214    3.8251
    2.3178    3.8203
    3.2214    3.6912
    3.4178    3.7067
    3.6928    3.8663
    3.8892    3.8731
    4.1642    4.0278
    4.3607    3.9661
    4.3607    3.8620
    4.5571    3.8512

    0.0000    4.4821
    0.1964    4.4887
    0.4714    4.2778
    0.6679    4.2788
    0.9429    3.9669
    1.1393    3.9514
    2.1214    3.9404
    2.3178    3.9427
    3.2214    4.0103
    3.4178    3.9980
    3.6928    3.9316
    3.8892    3.8946
    4.1642    4.0634
    4.3607    4.0441
    4.3607    3.9217
    4.5571    3.9157

    0.0000    4.4821
    0.1964    4.4888
    0.4714    4.3743
    0.6679    4.3743
    0.9429    4.1492
    1.1393    4.1496
    2.1214    4.0248
    2.3178    3.9829
    3.2214    4.2324
    3.4178    4.2269
    3.6928    4.0857
    3.8892    4.0834
    4.1642    4.0676
    4.3607    4.0682
    4.3607    4.1006
    4.5571    4.0830

    0.0000    4.5402
    0.1964    4.5388
    0.4714    4.4548
    0.6679    4.4583
    0.9429    4.4041
    1.1393    4.3928
    2.1214    4.1067
    2.3178    4.1399
    3.2214    4.4015
    3.4178    4.4062
    3.6928    4.2503
    3.8892    4.2560
    4.1642    4.0758
    4.3607    4.1082
    4.3607    4.2411
    4.5571    4.2487

    0.0000    5.0444
    0.1964    5.0417
    0.4714    4.8738
    0.6679    4.8729
    0.9429    4.4318
    1.1393    4.4467
    2.1214    4.4285
    2.3178    4.4303
    3.2214    4.6561
    3.4178    4.6584
    3.6928    4.3592
    3.8892    4.3660
    4.1642    4.2723
    4.3607    4.2929
    4.3607    4.3701
    4.5571    4.3792

    0.0000    5.0445
    0.1964    5.0418
    0.4714    5.0081
    0.6679    5.0060
    0.9429    4.9708
    1.1393    4.9698
    2.1214    4.9562
    2.3178    4.9557
    3.2214    4.8668
    3.4178    4.8648
    3.6928    4.7794
    3.8892    4.7791
    4.1642    4.5660
    4.3607    4.5657
    4.3607    4.7764
    4.5571    4.7757

    0.0000   10.3065
    0.1964   10.3992
    0.4714   10.7259
    0.6679   10.7958
    0.9429   11.5000
    1.1393   11.5190
    2.1214   11.8223
    2.3178   11.8224
    3.2214   11.2899
    3.4178   11.3183
    3.6928   11.6945
    3.8892   11.7073
    4.1642   11.7664
    4.3607   11.7677
    4.3607   11.6923
    4.5571   11.7014

    0.0000   11.1807
    0.1964   11.0368
    0.4714   11.4245
    0.6679   11.3350
    0.9429   11.8514
    1.1393   11.8478
    2.1214   11.8589
    2.3178   11.9160
    3.2214   11.7656
    3.4178   11.7414
    3.6928   11.9359
    3.8892   11.9809
    4.1642   11.8807
    4.3607   11.9676
    4.3607   11.9428
    4.5571   12.0018

    0.0000   11.7310
    0.1964   11.7731
    0.4714   11.9689
    0.6679   11.9857
    0.9429   12.1962
    1.1393   12.2124
    2.1214   12.1573
    2.3178   12.1198
    3.2214   12.2043
    3.4178   12.2588
    3.6928   12.2256
    3.8892   12.1875
    4.1642   12.3719
    4.3607   12.2643
    4.3607   12.2421
    4.5571   12.2020

    0.0000   12.7784
    0.1964   12.7979
    0.4714   12.6126
    0.6679   12.6202
    0.9429   12.4584
    1.1393   12.4550
    2.1214   12.4426
    2.3178   12.4729
    3.2214   12.5473
    3.4178   12.5162
    3.6928   12.5141
    3.8892   12.5349
    4.1642   12.4005
    4.3607   12.3712
    4.3607   12.4996
    4.5571   12.5100

    0.0000   12.7784
    0.1964   12.7979
    0.4714   12.6926
    0.6679   12.7103
    0.9429   12.5131
    1.1393   12.5592
    2.1214   12.6344
    2.3178   12.6558
    3.2214   12.5874
    3.4178   12.6011
    3.6928   12.6298
    3.8892   12.5994
    4.1642   12.5542
    4.3607   12.5734
    4.3607   12.6243
    4.5571   12.6398

    0.0000   12.7876
    0.1964   12.8193
    0.4714   12.8074
    0.6679   12.8256
    0.9429   12.7655
    1.1393   12.7754
    2.1214   12.8607
    2.3178   12.8446
    3.2214   12.6391
    3.4178   12.6470
    3.6928   12.6876
    3.8892   12.6897
    4.1642   12.7080
    4.3607   12.7051
    4.3607   12.7275
    4.5571   12.6713

    0.0000   13.1004
    0.1964   13.0722
    0.4714   13.0366
    0.6679   12.9791
    0.9429   13.0101
    1.1393   12.9052
    2.1214   13.0170
    2.3178   12.8966
    3.2214   12.9065
    3.4178   12.8767
    3.6928   12.8541
    3.8892   12.8203
    4.1642   12.8164
    4.3607   12.8346
    4.3607   12.7927
    4.5571   12.7664

    0.0000   13.1554
    0.1964   13.0751
    0.4714   13.0861
    0.6679   13.0860
    0.9429   13.0868
    1.1393   13.0662
    2.1214   13.2293
    2.3178   13.2227
    3.2214   13.0222
    3.4178   12.9814
    3.6928   13.0106
    3.8892   13.0415
    4.1642   12.9650
    4.3607   13.0208
    4.3607   13.0348
    4.5571   13.0557

    0.0000   13.1554
    0.1964   13.0751
    0.4714   13.2416
    0.6679   13.1426
    0.9429   13.2562
    1.1393   13.2380
    2.1214   13.3528
    2.3178   13.3379
    3.2214   13.2646
    3.4178   13.2558
    3.6928   13.2898
    3.8892   13.2698
    4.1642   13.2274
    4.3607   13.2233
    4.3607   13.3359
    4.5571   13.3361

    0.0000   13.4133
    0.1964   13.4857
    0.4714   13.3373
    0.6679   13.3744
    0.9429   13.3998
    1.1393   13.3719
    2.1214   13.4157
    2.3178   13.4540
    3.2214   13.4500
    3.4178   13.3922
    3.6928   13.5096
    3.8892   13.5470
    4.1642   13.6396
    4.3607   13.6385
    4.3607   13.4464
    4.5571   13.4663

    0.0000   13.4133
    0.1964   13.4857
    0.4714   13.4273
    0.6679   13.4688
    0.9429   13.5913
    1.1393   13.6096
    2.1214   13.6823
    2.3178   13.6929
    3.2214   13.5383
    3.4178   13.4839
    3.6928   13.7806
    3.8892   13.7301
    4.1642   13.7872
    4.3607   13.8334
    4.3607   13.6995
    4.5571   13.6610
```

Comment: It is impossible to tell if you do not provide further information. To understand if your calculation is on the right track, one needs to know the full workflow. This at least includes what material you are working on and what your `pw.x` input files look like (both `calculation='scf'` and `calculation='bands'`).

Comment: The input file you provided is for `bands.x` post-processing. It does not contain any information. A general remark: whenever you copy and paste some input/output files here on this website, try enclosing them as a `code block`. Lastly, please read [this](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/why-do-we-ask-you-to-use-code-blocks-rather-than-screenshots) and [this](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393/why-do-we-not-allow-links-to-google-drive-files).